# SpringBoot MultipartFile upload between Microservices using OpenFeign

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, openfeign

So i have 2 microservices on SpringBoot, A and B. An api call to A must be done from B and it requires the passing of the MultiPartFile using openfeign client.

Problem:
Run into following errors

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedRead(NioSocketImpl.java:283) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:309) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:982) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:244) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:343) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:754) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:689) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1618) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1523) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:527) ~[na:na]
    at feign.Client$Default.convertResponse(Client.java:82) ~[feign-core-10.4.0.jar:na]
    at feign.Client$Default.execute(Client.java:78) ~[feign-core-10.4.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.FeignLoadBalancer.execute(FeignLoadBalancer.java:93) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.FeignLoadBalancer.execute(FeignLoadBalancer.java:56) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient$1.call(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:104) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$3$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:303) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$3$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:287) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$3.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:231) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$3.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:228) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap$ConcatMapSubscriber.drain(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:286) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap$ConcatMapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:144) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:185) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:180) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:94) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:42) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber$1.call(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:127) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.enqueue(TrampolineScheduler.java:73) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.schedule(TrampolineScheduler.java:52) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:79) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:45) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$WeakSingleProducer.request(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:276) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:209) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:138) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:129) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10423) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10390) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:443) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single(BlockingObservable.java:340) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:112) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.LoadBalancerFeignClient.execute(LoadBalancerFeignClient.java:83) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:110) ~[feign-core-10.4.0.jar:na]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:80) ~[feign-core-10.4.0.jar:na]
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103) ~[feign-core-10.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy169.initiateDocContainer(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at one.captl.RESTful.service.LpRoundService.updateLpDocument(LpRoundService.java:230) ~[main/:na]
    at one.captl.RESTful.api.LpRoundController.updateLpDocs(LpRoundController.java:491) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:920) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:663) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:64) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

As can be seen from the calling logic, initiateDocContainer function of the FeignClient is called and works fine. Eureka discovery service is used for microservice discovery.

API endpoint in microservice A is as follows:

```
    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<Long> upload(@RequestParam("byEntityType") IdType byEntityType, @RequestParam("byEntityTypeAccessId")Long byEntityTypeAccessId,@RequestParam("userId") long userId,
                                       @RequestParam("docContainerId") long docContainerId,
                                       @RequestParam("document") MultipartFile file)
```

On referring to sources such as [openfeign issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/issues/62) and other stackoverflow issues, this is the config and feignclient that i tried. This does not work

Config class

```
import feign.codec.Encoder;
import feign.form.spring.SpringFormEncoder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.support.SpringEncoder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
class FeignConfig {
    @Autowired
    private ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters> messageConverters;

    @Bean
    Encoder feignFormEncoder()
    {
        return new SpringFormEncoder(new SpringEncoder(messageConverters));
    }
}
```

FeignClient

```
import one.captl.RESTful.model.enums.DocumentType;
import one.captl.RESTful.model.enums.IdType;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestPart;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.util.List;

// Must add application name to document microservice
@FeignClient(name = "document",contextId = "documentFeign",configuration = {FeignConfig.class})
public interface DocumentsFeignClient {
    @PostMapping(value = "api/v1/doc/upload",consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    ResponseEntity<Long> upload(@RequestParam("byEntityType") IdType byEntityType, @RequestParam("byEntityTypeAccessId") Long byEntityTypeAccessId, @RequestParam("userId") long userId,
                                @RequestParam("docContainerId") long docContainerId,
                                @RequestPart("document") MultipartFile file);

    @PostMapping(value = "api/v1/doc")
    long initiateDocContainer(@RequestParam("idType") IdType idType, @RequestParam("accessId") Long accessId, @RequestParam("documentType") DocumentType documentType, @RequestParam("fromId") long fromId,
                              @RequestParam("toIds") List<Long> toIds);

}
```

Calling logic

```
    public void updateLpDocument(Long Id, LpDocs lpDocs, Long fromUserId, List<Long> toIds, Optional<MultipartFile> file) {

        LpRound lpRound =lpRoundRepo.findById(Id).get();
        HashMap<LpDocs,Long> tempDocs= lpRound.getLpDocuments();

        long docContainerId = documentsFeignClient.initiateDocContainer(IdType.LpRoundId,Id,DocumentType.valueOf(lpDocs.name()),fromUserId,toIds);
        tempDocs.put(lpDocs,docContainerId);
        lpRound.setLpDocuments(tempDocs);

        if(file.isPresent()) {
            documentsFeignClient.upload(IdType.LpRoundId, Id, fromUserId, docContainerId, file.get());
        }
        lpRoundRepo.save(lpRound);
    }
```